# Firebase auth takes so much time to authenticate Android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to use Firebase auth with MVVM and Dependency Injection, the issue is that my auth state is stuck in Loading for several minutes before authentication, It takes so much time to authenticate. It was working fine until 2 days ago and I can't find a solution to it.

My ViewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class AppViewModel @Inject constructor(private val firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth) : ViewModel() {


    private val _register = MutableStateFlow<Resource<FirebaseUser>>(Resource.Unspecified())
    val register : Flow<Resource<FirebaseUser>> = _register

    private val _validation = Channel<RegisterFieldState>()
    val validation = _validation.receiveAsFlow()

  fun signUpWithEmail(email: String, password: String) {

            viewModelScope.launch {
                _register.emit(Resource.Loading())
            }
            firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    it.user?.let {
                        _register.value = Resource.Success(it)
                    }
                }
                .addOnFailureListener {
                    _register.value = Resource.Error(it.message.toString())
                }
    }
```

My register fragment

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class RegisterFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var _binding : FragmentRegisterBinding
    private val binding get() = _binding
    private val viewModel : AppViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        _binding = FragmentRegisterBinding.inflate(layoutInflater,container,false)
        return binding.root




    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.loginButton.setOnClickListener {
            signUp()
        }

    }

    private fun signUp(){
        binding.apply {
            viewModel.signUpWithEmail(email.text.toString(), password.text.toString())
            // val intent = Intent(this@RegisterActivity,HomeActivity::class.java)
            // startActivity(intent)
            lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
                viewModel.register.collect{
                    when(it){
                        is Resource.Loading -> {
                            Toast.makeText(context,"Loading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                        is Resource.Success -> {
                           // findNavController().navigate(R.id.loginFragment)
                            Toast.makeText(context,"Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            Log.d("Testing",it.toString())
                        }
                        is Resource.Error -> {
                            Toast.makeText(context,"Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            Log.d("Testing Failure",it.toString())
                        }
                        else -> {
                            Toast.makeText(context,"N/A", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()}
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Solution : Downgraded my emulator version to 31.2.9

Comment: When it comes to MVVM, most likely you should use a repository class too. All Firebase calls should be added there and from inside a ViewModel only call the corresponding methods. Since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help you get the idea. If you want to see some code, here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle).

Comment: I found a solution to my problem by downgrading the emulator version.
But thank you anyways, I will check the link u sent me to improve my code